# django custom model manager throwing error

Tags: python, django, django-custom-manager

I am trying to build a model for a django website I am working on, and I have all the fields as you can see in the below reviews model. Now I have read how to implement a custom model manager, and for whatever reason for the line of code: "object = ReviewsManager", django throws an error saying that it is an undefined variable. All the examples I have seen do the exact same thing, but they apparently work just fine, any idea whats going on? To be clear I have imported everything that needs importing already, so I know that isnt the issue.
As a side note I should mention I am running django 1.6, in case that matters.

```
//This is the model itself
class Reviews(models.Model):
    mentor_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False);
    review_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False);
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    stars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=1);
    ----> object = ReviewsManager

//Trying to use this manager below
---> class ReviewsManager(models.Manager):    

    def getReviewsByMentorId(self, id):
       r = Reviews.objects.filter(mentor_id=id);
       return r;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

- You try to use the `ReviewsManager` class before it is defined. Move your class definition up so it's above your `Review` class, or move it to a separate file and import that file before using the class.
- You are not instantiating your manager class. After you've solved the first issue, this will raise another error. Use `objects = ReviewsManager()` instead.
- As Prashant said, it should be `objects`, not `object`

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
----> object = ReviewsManager
```

to

```
----> objects = ReviewsManager()        ## you should use objects
```

Code should be like :

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    mentor_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False);
    review_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False);
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    stars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=1);
    objects = ReviewsManager()
```

`class ReviewsManager(models.Manager):    

    def getReviewsByMentorId(self, id):
        r = Reviews.objects.filter(mentor_id=id);
        return r;`